# Parsing data from Firebase Database

Tags: android, parsing, firebase-realtime-database, model

Hi I am developing a chat application using Firebase database.

below is the structure of my database for user on Firebase
[image]

The structure of my model classes for User currently is

```
 public class User {
   Credential credentials;
   List<Conversation> conversationList;
 }

 public class Credential implements Parcelable {

   private String name="";
   private String email="";
   private String profilePicLink="";
 }
```

I am not getting what should be the structure of conversations list as per the structure on firebase db .

TIA.

Comment: So what are you getting by now? And how do you get the data from the db? Please post your code.

Comment: @Yuliwee I am able to fetch the user object with credentials . the problem is  to fetch conversations list as each conversation is saved under a dynamic key. The error is " No setter/field for conversations found on class User"
One solution is to again fetch conversations by the user id from db when required. or i think the only one ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Update the rules for your database to allow reads and writes from all users, 
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true"
  }
}
```

Reference:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data

Answer (score 0):

Firebase stores its data as key-value pair rather than a list. As per your snapshot, a user has two main Hashmaps i.e. **conversations** and **credentials**. Therefore, you can create your models as:

```
public class User {
   Hashmap<String, String> credentials;
   Hashmap<String, Hashmap<String, String>> conversationList;
 }

 public class Credential implements Parcelable {

   private String name="";
   private String email="";
   private String profilePicLink="";

public void setModel(Hashmap<String, String> data) {
//assign values to your model here
}
 }
```